# Why isn't MVC URL available?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've created a new MVC web app in VS.NET 2010.  I can access localhost/Home/Contact without issue.  That's a method that comes built into the example app.

I added another method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(ClassA content)
{
  return new HttpStatusCodeResult(204);
}
```

When I try to access this method using:

localhost/Home/MyMethod

I get a 404 error.  I've tried directly in the browser (GET) and also through POSTing.  Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you show us _how_ you post? It's by design that you can't reach the action through a get request, that's why you decorate it with the `HttpPost` attribute.

Comment: Try removing `[HttpPost]` and then visit it in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpPost` attribute indicates that the action can only be accessed through a `POST` request, it protects you from other request types (GET, PUT etc.).

`POST` requests will also work without the attribute, but `GET` requests will too! This might expose database queries which inserts, updates or removes data through GET requests, which is a bad practice. Imagine Google indexing a page like this: `www.mysite.com/Users/Delete/{id}`, if you accept `GET` requests, it might delete your complete user-base.

`GET` is to retrieve data, and `POST` is to submit data. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) for more info.

There are different ways to initiate a `POST` request.

You can wrap a form inside `Html.BeginForm()`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName);

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password);
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.UserName);

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

Or via `jQuery.post()`:

```
$.post(
    '@Url.Action("MyMethod", "Home")',
    {
        // data for ClassA.
        name: $('#username').val(); // example.
    },
    function (result) {
        // handle the result.
    });
```

But this `GET` request *won't* work if you decorated your action with the `HttpPost` attribute:

```
$.get(
    '@Url.Action("MyMethod", "Home")',
    function (result) {
        // this will not work.
    });
```

Or if you try to access it through your browser.
Also see [this blogpost](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/10/aspnet-mvc-httppost-action-filter.html).

Comment: Will the 204 still be returned in my example or does the HttpPost block it?

Comment: @4thSpace I think it should, you could go and try with Fiddler/Firebug if it works. Why do you want that `HTTP 204` so badly though?

Comment: The POST'er requires it.

Comment: @4thSpace if you put a breakpoint in the action, does it get hit?

Answer (score 0):

This method only accessed by POST.

Comment: Thanks.  If someone is doing a POST to that method and I don't have the HttpPost attribute, it should still work right?  What is the benefit of using HttpPost - just restriction for POST?

Comment: Also, I'm returning the 204.  I should be able to capture and display that return in the POST'ing page right?  That would solve my problem.